# what "sudo bash -c" means in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script file that, in one of the lines I have "sudo bash -c", what is the -c argument for ?

thanks

Comment: `man bash` will tell you what `-c` means in that context (it's an argument to bash, not to sudo).

Comment: Well, it is an argument to `sudo`, the same as `bash` here is an argument to `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From le manual of the bash:

-c string
If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ and the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before" therein.

Comment: We responded at the same time. 
Thank you for your clarification

Comment: The objection is not that you were duplicating my comment, but that you were duplicating answers on the three (and many more) copies of this same question already added to the knowledge base by others, long before this instance of the question was even asked.